# Developer connection proxy tool

Tags: debugging, proxy, web

Sometime ago I used a tool (I think it was written in Java), it had a general "blue" theme to it and allows to grab outgoing HTTP requests and alter values in the request/response based on certain flags/regex, all sorts of good web-debugging things.

Does anyone remember by chance what the name of that tool was? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are two HTTP Proxy tools that would do what you need;

- [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/)
- [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/)

They're both written in Java -- Paros is quite Blue, almost purple. Maybe that's the one you're referring to? Burp seems to be a little orange-themed these days :)

Comment: Wohoo! it's burp suite! the windows themselves in the tool are blue so that is what I meant :) Thanks!

Comment: No worries, Burp Suite is my favourite of the two -- Paros is a bit bear-bones but also gets the job done :)

Comment: I am guessing you know of it, but Fiddler is also excellent :)

Comment: +1 it's great THAT question could be answered ^^

Answer (score 0):

Paros hasnt been updated for *years*.

Have a look at the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) - its a fork of Paros, is completely free and open source and has been significantly enhanced.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)